# Angular <select><option> tags not being displayed in the browser but present in source html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I added a dropdown list to the FormGroup but it's not being displayed in the browser. Checked the page Html source on chrome and the `<select><option></option></select>` is present but not displayed for some reason.
`mainForm` is the FormGroup and  FormControl for the dropdown is `languages`.

```
this.mainForm = fBuilder.group({'textToBeTranslated':['',Validators.required],'source':['',Validators.required],'target':['',Validators.required],'languages':['French'],'submit':[]});
```

Called `this.mainForm.markAllAsTouched()`

1. this.mainForm.controls['languages'].touched prints `true`
2. this.mainForm.controls['languages'].value prints the default value `French`

The above observation helps conclude that the FormControl `languages` is present in the FormGroup.

[![

```html
<form [formGroup]="mainForm"  (ngSubmit)="setAllAsTouched() && mainForm.valid && clicked()" >
  <div>

    <h3>Language 1</h3>
    <select id="languages" [formControl]="mainForm.controls['languages']"  name="languages">
     
        <option *ngFor="let language of languages" >{{language}}</option>
    </select>
    <!--label for="languages">Language</label-->
    <h3>Language 2</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div  *ngIf="!mainForm.controls['textToBeTranslated'].valid && (mainForm.controls['textToBeTranslated'].touched)" class="input-field col s6">
    <p style="color:red">*Text To Translate is Required*</p>
  </div>
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="textToBeTranslated" name="textToBeTranslated" [formControl]="mainForm.controls['textToBeTranslated']" type="text" class="validate" #textToBeTranslated>
    <label for="textToBeTranslated">Enter Text To Be Translated:</label>
  </div>
  <!-- *ngIf="mainForm.submitted && !mainForm.controls['source'].valid && (mainForm.controls['source'].touched)" -->
  <!--*ngIf="!mainForm.controls['source'].valid && (mainForm.controls['source'].touched)"-->
  <!--div  *ngIf="!mainForm.controls['source'].valid && (mainForm.controls['source'].touched)" class="input-field col s6"-->
  <div  *ngIf="!mainForm.controls['source'].valid && (mainForm.controls['source'].touched)" class="input-field col s6">
    <p style="color:red">*Source is Required*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="source"  name="source" [formControl]="mainForm.controls['source']" type="text" class="validate" >
    <label for="source">Enter Source:</label>
  </div>
  <div  *ngIf="!mainForm.controls['target'].valid && (mainForm.controls['target'].touched)" class="input-field col s6">
    <p style="color:red">*Target is Required*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="target" name="target" [formControl]="mainForm.controls['target']" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="target" >Target: </label>
 </div>

<br>
<Button id="b1" type="sumbit" name="submit"  >{{buttonDisplay}}</Button>
<app-displayresult [buttonChildText]="translatedText"></app-displayresult>
</form>
```

Image shows the Html source:
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3o4c.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3o4c.png)

I did Google for help but almost every post I found is about dropdown not displaying the default value. In my case, the dropdown(outline) is not displayed at all. Is there something that I am missing? I also did try adding materialize CSS but that didn't work either.

languages: `languages : Array<String> = ['French','English'];`

Comment: Can you share the value of `languages`?

Comment: @iamentafaz yep. Edited the post to add it. In the Html source, I can see `<option _ngcontent-ntu-c46="">French</option>` and `<option _ngcontent-ntu-c46="">English</option>`. So I think iterating with `ngFor` is working as expected.

Comment: Yeah seems like a CSS issue now.

Comment: @iamentafaz I also placed a `<select></select>` element directly in index.html (not in the app-root). That didn't work either. But creating a regular HTML file with a select tag in it works. Not sure why it is not being rendered with the default chrome style for select when used with angular.

Comment: @ShayD Tried that as well. Didn't work :/

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Comment: @iamentafaz Thanks for your support. Just hosted it on stackblitz. And thanks a lot for sharing the tool. Never knew this existed!! https://stackblitz.com/github/mathewsmathai1/AngularTranslator/tree/FormBuilder

Comment: Got it! Like I told you earlier it's a `CSS` Issue. I have to put an answer to show you the `CSS` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `select` element has a `display` property `none` set by `materialize.min.css`.
You need to set a `CSS` of `select` element to `display: block` and put `label` before `select` for better visibility with `position: relative`.
I have updated the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3bta7q?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Adding the image for your reference:

[image]

Modified HTML:

```
<label for="languages" style="position: relative">Language</label>
<select
      id="languages"
      style="border-style: solid; border-color: red;display: block;"
      [formControl]="mainForm.controls['languages']"
      name="languages"
    >
      <!--[formControl]="mainForm.controls['languages']" -->

      <option *ngFor="let language of languages">{{language}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem Solved :) One more doubt. Is it a default of angular setting `display` to `none`? Because even if I use a simple `<select id="cars" name="cars" value="Volvo" > <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> </select>` , it does not get displayed even if no style is applied. But the same as a stand alone HTML file displays it on chrome (not angular app).

Comment: No! It's not related to default angular setting at all. The issue occurs because `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css` you have added this library which is overriding default `select` css of browser. The way I see it, you could set `display: block` to `select` element in your global css with an `!important`. Something like `display: block !important`. Also please mark the answer useful if you think so.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I am new to frontend development. This clears the basics a lot.